# DNS Over VPN for non domain connected Devices

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, vpn

I have a VPN setup for admin users only.
It is configured to forward DNS details on from the internal DNS servers (windows).
When a computer that is on the domain logs on remotely through the VPN client they are able to resolve hostnames however a device that has never been on the domain cannot access the DNS because it is not setup as a public DNS server.
I dont want to make a Public DNS server if I can avoid it.
What would be the best approach (security and least changes) to having non domain members (devices) access an internal DNS server through VPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending upon which VPN software you are using you should be able to specify which DNS servers that the clients receive when they are allocated their VPN IP address when they connect. This assumes that you are using a full tunnelling VPN and not a SSL VPN or similar.

From memory I think some of the SSL VPNs allow for mapping or proxying of internal to external addresses through the SSL VPN connection.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's simply a matter of the non-domain clients failing to ask for the fully qualified domain name of the host.  For example, a computer that connects to your domain and looks up "exchange" might get a SERVFAIL response, but it actually *would* get an answer if it looked up "exchange.yourdomain.local" instead.

Do you get a different result if one of your non-domain VPN client tries to resolve an FQDN instead of just a hostname?